# "Use undeclared identifier" error

Tags: xcode4.5, iphone-5, appdelegate, undeclared-identifier

I know that error is very common but I'm working to get my app iPhone 5 ready ! I preferred to use a new storyboard file for iPhone 5 .. but I'm stuck on that error could any one help me please ? here's my appdelegate.m

[appdelegate.m(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgKiJ.png)
[appdelegate.m(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPm88.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved .. there was a missing `}` at the end